# Merging 2 arrays of CMTimeRanges - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a part of my app where I have to take to arrays of timespan objects and merge them with 1 taking precedence over the other, for example array 1 might be:

> 0: 0-4
>
> 1: 4-6
>
> 2: 6-9

And the one that i am merging with that takes precedence

> 0: 2-7
>
> 1: 7-8

SO I need to merge the 2 and end up with:

> 0: 0-2
>
> 1: 2-7
>
> 2: 7-8
>
> 3: 8-9

I am a little stuck on how to recursively take care of such a task, there might be a few time ranges in each array, but there might also be hundreds.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand. What happened to 0-4 and 4-6 ?

Comment: The 2nd array overwrote them.

Comment: What criteria is then used ? Where does 8-9 come from ?

Comment: After 7-8 happens, you are left with the 8-9 part left from the first array's 6-9